# Cant access oracle db with my Java spring boot Docker image because of the error: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Unknown host specified

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, docker

I can not connect oracle db in Docker image whereas I can connect to it via IntelliJ. The project is a spring boot maven project. Here is regarding part of my application.yml file:

```
    datasource:
      url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@host_name:port/service_name
      username: username
      password: password
      driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
      show-sql: true
      format_sql: true
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

With this configuration I can connect to the oracle using **ojdbc6.ja**r. However when I try to run project with docker-compose with the same configuration I can not connect to db. It gives **oracle.net.ns.NetException: Unknown host specified** error. This is my docker-compose:

```
database:
    container_name: db
    image: db
    build: ./
    ports:
      - "8091:8091"
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@host_name:port/service_name
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=username
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=password
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DIALECT=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
    networks:
      - my_network1
```

Is it related that I am using host_name instead of IP? I do not know the IP address of the db server. If that is the problem I would be glad if you tell me any way to get IP from host name if it is possible.

Why docker-compose can not connect the oracle db? I am new with Docker. Is there anything I am missing? Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is `host_name`; is it another container name, the special name `localhost`, the FQDN of some other server `database.example.com`?  Does your host have any special DNS settings or modifications to `/etc/hosts` that Docker might not pick up?

Comment: Just add an IP address of the database hostname into the special section `extra_hosts` of your docker compose file

Comment: Hi, I am using external oracle db, I finally learnt its IP and it worked. However now I am getting "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" error in docker. I checked all the tables and they are all exists. Everthing works fine when I run the project on Intellij. But docker gives this error. Could you please help me about that?

Answer (score 0):

When you run your container using `docker-compose`, a new network is created (in your case you called it `my_network1`) for the container to use. This network has no knowledge of you host name `host_name` or a DNS server able to resolve `host_name`, so this explains the exception thrown.

Your options are:

- Use the host's IP address and avoid the DNS resolution altogether
- Configure your container to use a specific DNS server
- Configure your container with a statically resolved `host_name` (as if you directly edit `/etc/hosts`)

Examples:

***Static host resolution***

```
database:
    container_name: db
    image: db
    build: ./
    ports:
      - "8091:8091"
    extra_hosts:
         "host_name:1.2.3.4"
```

Reference [here](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#extra_hosts).

***Use specific DNS server***

```
database:
    container_name: db
    image: db
    build: ./
    ports:
      - "8091:8091"
    dns:
         - 10.0.0.1
```

Reference [here](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#dns).